# How to iterate all mail folders in all accounts with ID and name in Outlook 2016 for Mac

Tags: macos, email, outlook, applescript, directory

I use raw queries to sort mail in Outlook 2016 for Mac using the "smart folders". The queries work well with folder ID's. I've used a script to tell me the Current Folder I'm clicked on in Outlook, but I'd like to get a script together that just prints out all the folders for all the mail accounts with ID's so that I have a cheat sheet of folder ID's and names. I can get all the ID's to print, just not the names with them. Anybody know how to do this?

Here's the code I have so far, just need the name to print out.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
set allMailFolders to get mail folders
repeat with currentFolder in allMailFolders
    get currentFolder
end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the properties of the folder class is name. You can print that. Here's a slight modification of your script that should demonstrate:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set folderNames to ""
    set allMailFolders to get mail folders
    repeat with currentFolder in allMailFolders
        set folderNames to folderNames & id of currentFolder & " - " & name of currentFolder & " " -- or put a newline here
    end repeat
end tell
```